# Agent oriented distributed thread pools

Tags: agent, threadpoolexecutor, distributed-system

Hazelcast provide a distributed executor service that can be used for CPU-bound applications running on the cluster. I want to know about Hazelcast alternative that is agent based and provide elastic executor service that is agent oriented and shrinks and grow itself. Kindly suggest me the frameworks or libraries that provide agent oriented thread pool.